# Apex Compiler Changes

Tags: apex

It appears that recently the Apex compiler has changed - for the better it seems.

Here are some typical messages:

Example 1:

```
String s = "hey";
```

Results:

```
Error:Error:line (6)Unrecognized symbol '"', which is not a valid Apex identifier.
Error:Error:line (6)Unrecognized symbol '"', which is not a valid Apex identifier.
Error:Error:line (1)". Message was "no viable alternative at character '"'".
Error:Error:line (1)". Message was "no viable alternative at character '"'".
Error:Error:line (6)Variable does not exist: hey
```

Example 2:

```
Integer x = 0
String y = 'something';
```

Results:

```
Error:(7, 5) unexpected syntax: 'missing SEMICOLON at 'String''
```

Example 3:

```
if (true == true))
```

Results:

```
Error:(6, 22) unexpected token: ')'
```

Example 4:

```
String[] stuff = new String[]{'whats up'
```

Results:

```
Error:(9, 5) unexpected syntax: 'mismatched input 'VestingData' expecting RCURLY'
```

The messages appear more specific and clear - however, I can't find any org which still has the old compiler to compare with.

Does anyone have any insight into this pleasant phenomenon?

Specifically:

- Are there any important differences between the old compiler and the new?
- Does the new compiler provide any new functionality that I could take
  advantage of?
- How has the apparent speed increase been achieved?
- Is there a concrete roadmap of future updates that we should know about?

Comment: Presume you've seen this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yc5FrviQqO8? Lots about caching but talks about new compiler rollout too.

Comment: @KeithC I was at that talk, but it's nearly a year old now - I was after some more up-to-date information, if available.

Comment: Yep will be interesting to see what further info is available.

Comment: As far as I know, they haven't put it in the release notes or posted it anywhere. So, until they do, you're going to have more questions than answers. I myself would love to know more.

Comment: I've also noticed it won't let you put an OR statement into a SOQL WHERE clause that also contains an AND statement without wrapping it in parenthesis, which is a nice little catch for a common error.

Comment: @JasonBenkert Helpful if API versioned...

Comment: Could it be tied to the [Release version](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_releases_view?release=190000000)? Most orgs are currently on 17 Patch 19.2 with a few exceptions. AP9, CS116, CS115 are still on 18.0 (AWS hosted?).

Comment: Well, I suppose if anyone had access to one of the 18.0 versions, they might be able to check... I suppose it might be nice to know which version you are compiling to - on the other hand, since we have no option as to which compiler we use, it's a moot point.

Comment: See https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000264742&type=1&language=en_US for the documentation on expected behavioral changes beyond messages.

Comment: There are things that I had assumed were tied to the Apex compiler [coming in Winter '18](https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/885610480575823872). Could test those for confirmation.

Comment: Commented on a question a few days ago where the message the OP posted looked odd. More specific that what used to. Google search of message returned no results other than the question here. So looks like something def has changed

Comment: In addition to more specific errors, I've noticed that the new compiler doesn't give up and die at the first sign of an error like it used to.  Where possible, it will report multiple compilation errors.  This can reduce the number of code-compile-fix cycles when writing new code.

Comment: @JasonClark I noticed that too - cool eh!

Comment: I won't believe it until my `switch` statement compiles :)

Comment: Looks like Developer console will start using the Apex Language Services too just like VSCode and Force.com IDE.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can confirm that the new Apex compiler appears to be in place.

I took the first example from [Winter '18 Apex Compiler Changes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000264742&type=1&language=en_US) and tested in out in my dev org. It no longer compiles with Summer'17 Patch 19.2. It isn't immediately clear if the Apex compiler is tied to the release version.

[image]

Winter 18 came early! At least as far as the compiler is concerned.

The help article linked above contains the "important differences between the old compiler and the new".

I suspect you will see some new Apex functionality going forward once the compiler is settled in place. These would usually be heralded by the release notes. Things like <strike>[Deployments Now Recompile of All Apex Code](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_apex_deploy_triggers_recompile.htm?edition=&impact=) and</strike> [the @isTest(isParallel=true)](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_apex_annotation_istest_isparallel.htm?edition=&impact=) spring to mind as being related to the new compiler. This is just a guess on my part.

Comment: Awesome!!! I just read that article - thanks for finding it - very good information to know. And yes, there were probably other things that would have been good to have in this drop, but perhaps there'll be more coming down the line.

Comment: I can say that the deployment recompilation is not related to the new compiler. I've been using the pilot of that feature for a while internally.

Comment: @ca_peterson Fair enough. I'm not even sure about my isParallel example either. Only reasoning was it was bumped from the last release. Like it couldn't go out without the compiler change. I'm just guessing though.